# Laravel getAttribute() on eloquent?

Tags: laravel

so i just wondered, if something like this is possible, since my code does not work.

```
protected $appends = ['position_name'];

public function getPositionNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\EmployeePosition', 'employee_position_id')->name;
}
```

Can I append the name of Eloquen relationship model?

edit: so far, i am using this:

```
foreach ($employees as $e) {
    $e->position_name = $e->position->name;
}
```

Comment: What is your goal, what will you do with the employees, sent them over api, serialize? Use them later in blade of something else? The best solution depends on your goal.

Comment: i have two model Employee and EmployeePosition. i am sending them to mobile app as a json. so no blade there anymore.

Comment: its bad. it will produce n+1 problem. please stick with `$e->position->name;`. make sure you use `with`. If dont, it will also produce n+1

Comment: what do you mean with `with`? should I use the `foreach` in controller? can you elaborate on this? also, if you could post it as an answer, it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I needed to use the relation defined before.

```
protected $appends = ['position_name'];

public function position()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\EmployeePosition', 'employee_position_id');
}

public function getPositionNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->position->name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating an accessor that looks up a value in another model and appending this field by using `$appends` is bad practice and will lead to n+1 queries whenever you fetch your Employee model. You should avoid doing this and just use `$employee->position->name`.

You should also make sure to use `Employee::with('position')` when you need to show the position name, so that the position model is fetched in a single query.

If the position name is something that you need in all your `Employee` queries, then you can set the Employee to always eager load the `position` by defining the following inside your Employee model:

```
    /**
     * The relationships that should always be loaded.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['position'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments i'd suggest to use the laravel default solution for your problems [API resrouces](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources)

eg

```php
class EmployeeResource extends JsonResource
{
   
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'position_name' => $this->position->name,
        ];
    }
}
```

note: using the `with` as other people suggested to preload information can increase performance by reducing the amount of queries, if you are returning a collection of employees.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just create a model with position names and reference it to the position id in the other mode by using eloquent relationships.